# Webpage doesn't update after changing files via FTP

Tags: html, ftp, web

I have a website with a domain and host. I sometimes change some pages and upload them via FTP (I'm using FileZilla). Tough, when I enter the webpage from the domain, the latest changes doesn't appear. I have checked many times the `html` files I've changed and they all look correctly uploaded to the host. But when I save the `html` page and check its code, the changes doesn't appear as expected. Why are the changes aren't being updated when browsing the webpage and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try refreshing the page using CTRL+F5, if it's not working, clean browser cache.

Comment: Well that did work, but how can I ensure that every single visitor will get the update? (Thinking mostly of frequent visitors)

Comment: Try adding something like this to your updated pages: 
"?ver=1.0" This method is used for css files, I don't know other ways right of the top of my head. :)

Comment: and what about if this doesn't work? any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Clean your browser Cache or try opening a private navigation window.

Answer (score 2):

Your Browser will Cache files so it doesn't have to load them every time. Usually refreshing will solve the issue but a surefire way is to enable the "disable browser cache" option in Chrome's dev console (firefox may have something similar).

When you open the dev console there is a gear in the upper right that opens the options menu. In the "General" tab the "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" option is available. after enabling this just refresh the page with the console open and it will download all of the latest files from your server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running ng build before uploading the website to FTP? If your website is made on Angular then ng build is must to update the new changes. I got the same problem and ng build worked for me :)